# extension of a principal connection

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles

I am trying to prove the following: Suppose that $\alpha:H\to G$ is a Lie group homomorphism and let $P\to M$ be a principal $H$-bundle and $Q\to M$ a principal $G$-bundle. Suppose further that there is a connection 1-form $\vartheta_P$ on $P$. I want to show that if 
$$
\varphi:P\to Q
$$
is an extension of $P$ to $G$, then there is a (unique?) connection $\vartheta_Q$ on $Q$ such that 
$$
\varphi^*\vartheta_Q = \alpha_*\circ \vartheta_P
$$

I am having difficulty trying to define $\vartheta_Q$. Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks!